# How many possible interpretations of 1 IPv4 address?

Tags: networking, ip, network-protocols

How many ways can 1 IPv4 address be interpreted, considering subnet masks? According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#IPv4_subnetting), it seems like there are 32 possible subnet masks to 1 IP address, but I don't know.

It's not clear to me if a "network mask" is the same as a "subnet mask"; is there such a thing as applying more than 1 mask to an IP address?

Comment: Duplicate question from same author:  http://serverfault.com/questions/486860/how-many-possible-ip-ways-to-interpret-1-ipv4-address-including-masks

Comment: There are 2^32 possible subnet masks, minus a few that don't make sense like 0.0.0.0 and ff.ff.ff.ff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

network mask and subnet mask are essentially the same thing although there may be different representations. 255.255.255.0 or /24 are both mask representations.  A give IP address can fall under different net masks, but there are some standard guidelines.  Class A networks are generally lower numbers in the first octet.  10.0.0.0 is a Class A private space with a mask of 255.0.0.0  What that means is 10.anything is part of that network and should not be routed outside that network.  you can do things like superneting which means change the subnet to something like 255.252.0.0 which limits the addresses in the network but is not a class a b or c. class B network is 255.255.0.0 .  Class C is 255.255.255.0 .  Class C is more commonly seen in home environments with a private address space of 192.168.x.0-255.  as far as interpreting an ip address, any address is 1 address. the subnet mask tells you if it is a broadcast address(highest address) or a prefix(lowest address) or a valid address in the address space.  it also tells a router if it should route the packet or not.